# Cisco IP Phone TFTP Error/Timeout

Tags: cisco, pbx, tftp, freepbx

I'm trying to get **Cisco 7942G IP phone** working on **FreeBPX** setup. It has issues with getting things over tftp. I tried hard reset thing and I'm getting this in tftpd log:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tail -f /var/log/messages | grep in.tftpd
Jul 29 11:18:02 localhost in.tftpd[4487]: RRQ from 172.22.225.60 filename SoftKeyDPN.xml
Jul 29 11:26:20 localhost in.tftpd[4664]: RRQ from 172.22.225.94 filename term42.default.loads
Jul 29 11:26:24 localhost in.tftpd[4665]: RRQ from 172.22.225.94 filename term42.default.loads
Jul 29 11:26:28 localhost in.tftpd[4666]: RRQ from 172.22.225.94 filename term42.default.loads
Jul 29 11:26:35 localhost in.tftpd[4671]: RRQ from 172.22.225.94 filename term42.default.loads
Jul 29 11:26:39 localhost in.tftpd[4672]: RRQ from 172.22.225.94 filename term42.default.loads
Jul 29 11:26:43 localhost in.tftpd[4674]: RRQ from 172.22.225.94 filename term42.default.loads
Jul 29 11:26:47 localhost in.tftpd[4679]: RRQ from 172.22.225.94 filename term42.default.loads
```

It's number 94.

Still it keeps rebooting and trying to get firmware. Before reset picture was pretty much the same, except it was after **SEP*.cnf.xml**, **SoftKeyDPN.xml** and **dialplan.xml**.

The phone log was telling about TFTP Error and TFTP timeout.

All this files are present anyway, I could get them by very tftp from another linux-based system (although it took much time - SEP config file 8Kb size was downloaded after 6 seconds! That's a quite delay, no?). Other IP phones had no troubles receiving their config, by the way. On this very line, also.

DHCP is on, option 150 is specified. It's elastix btw, CentOS based I belive.
TFTP config below:

```
[root@localhost xinetd.d]# cat tftp
# default: off
# description: The tftp server serves files using the trivial file transfer \
#       protocol.  The tftp protocol is often used to boot diskless \
#       workstations, download configuration files to network-aware printers, \
#       and to start the installation process for some operating systems.
service tftp
{
        socket_type             = dgram
        protocol                = udp
        wait                    = yes
        user                    = root
        server                  = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
        server_args             = -s -vv /tftpboot --verbose
        disable                 = no
        per_source              = 11
        cps                     = 100 2
        flags                   = IPv4
}
[root@localhost xinetd.d]#
```

I've no idea where to start digging. Any advice would help.

Comment: Check your duplex setting on the server and under Port settings on the phone. Make sure they match.  just an idea.

Comment: What state is the phone in? Has it ever worked? If you put config in manually in the settings on the phone, does it work? If it's looking for SEPDefault that sounds like it's on the Cisco Skinny firmware instead of the SIP firmware - is that what you intend?

Comment: Fergus: kinda problem, since it refuses to load beyond update screen after hard reset.

Comment: It worked.. Strangely, let's say. It was selective about port it is installed on: for example it worked on my port, but didn't on colleague's one. And it refused to work with two line config, just with one. It's not looking for SEPDefault, I meant SEP_887556..mac_address_bla_bla_thing.cnf.xml. It was using sip firmware.